Dimension of the space of primitive forms
Consider $E := \mathbb R^{2n}$ with its standard symplectic form $\omega$, almost complex structure $J$ and metric $g$.
The operator "wedge with omega" $L : \Lambda_\mathbb C^* E \to \Lambda_\mathbb C^{*+2} E = v \mapsto \omega \wedge v$ has an adjoint $\Lambda:\Lambda_\mathbb C^* E \to \Lambda_\mathbb C^{*-2} E $ "contraction by omega". The kernel of $\Lambda$ is the set of primitive forms.
For each $j$ there we can set $P^j = \ker \Lambda \cap \Lambda_\mathbb C^j E$ so that primitive forms are $P = \bigoplus_j P^j$ and $\Lambda_\mathbb C^j E = P^j\oplus L(\Lambda_\mathbb C^{j-2} E)$ (at least for $j<n$ so that $L$ is injective).
This is found in many books and is the preamble to the Lefschetz decomposition theorem.
However I cannot find explicitely the following:

What is the (complex) dimension of $P^j$ for $j<n$?

We know that $P^j = 0$ for $j>n$.

I'll talk about $\mathbb C^n$ everywhere because old habits die hard [edit] and as Ted Shifrin points out it's necessary to answer the question.
Set $W = \mathbb C^n$ and fix some $k \leq n$. We will also agree to write $V = W \oplus \overline W$ and have
$$
\bigwedge{}^{\!\!k} V^*
= \bigoplus_{p+q = k} \bigwedge{}^{\!\!p}\, W^* \otimes \bigwedge{}^{\!\!q}\, \overline W^*
$$
for the space of complex $k$-forms. These are the complex-valued forms that can be written as sums of $(p,q)$-forms.
Now, the map $\Lambda : \bigwedge^k V^* \to \bigwedge^{k-2} V^*$ is surjective and its kernel is the space of primitive forms, so there is an exact sequence
$$
0 \longrightarrow 
P^k \longrightarrow
\bigwedge{}^{\!\!k}\, V^* \longrightarrow
\bigwedge{}^{\!\!k-2}\, V^* \longrightarrow
0.
$$
Therefore
$$
\operatorname{dim} P^k
= \binom{2n}{k} - \binom{2n}{k-2}.
$$

How do you know that is surjective?

It's the adjoint of the Lefschetz operator ("wedge with $\omega$"), which is injective.

But you need to complexify. After all, the Kähler form is not holomorphic.

@TedShifrin I don’t follow. This is a linear algebra question, there are no holomorphic forms to consider.

I understand that, but the Kähler form is a $(1,1)$ form. You need $V\oplus \bar V$ for the linear algebra. For starters, the dimension is wrong with $k=2$.

@TedShifrin I see what you mean, you’re right. I’m too used to thinking in bundles.

The edit helps, but the dimensions certainly are not right, are they?
